# Selenium upload images

Tags: java, selenium

I want to upload the Image with the help of selenium webdriver code.can anyone help me for the same.I will provide  the steps for uploading image in My application.

1. In my application "Browse" Button is displayed in creation screen.
2. After clicking on Browse button window page will be displayed.
3. I have to select one image from the window and click on open.
4. It will redirect to my application with the name of the image which is selected in the image field.
5. The Image field is not editable(It would take name of the image which u selected.).

   I am able to click  browse button with selenium code.

HERE COMES MY ISSUES:Window screen is opened.But i cant able to interact(select an image and click on open button) in the window page as there is no firepath.

can anyone help me with the solution as soon as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
driver.findElement(By.id("btn_Browse")).click(); 
driver.findElement(By.id("logo")).sendKeys("c:\\ Image.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Autoit for handling file upload window while using selenium. Follow the below steps.

1) Download [Autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) and install it.

2) Then write the following code in a notepad. Change the file path in below code to the file path you are trying to upload from your selenium script. Save it as `uploadhandler.au3`. Note that the extension should be au3.

```
WinActivate("Choose file");
Local $file = "c:\yourpath\howtoupload.doc"
ControlSetText("Choose file", "", "Edit1", $file )
ControlClick("Choose file", "", "Button2")
```

3) Right click on that saved script file and click on "Compile script" from context menu.    This will generate `uploadhandler.exe` file.

4) Place this uploadhandler.exe file in your local drive and run this exe file in your selenium-java code wherever you need to upload the file using the below code.

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\path for your exe file\\uploadhandler.exe");
```

Ex:-

```
driver.findelement(byid("browse")).click();
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\path for your exe file\\uploadhandler.exe");
//rest of your selenium code continues here.
```

Comment: I tried ur code.WebElement click=( driver.findElement(By.id("bckBlack")));
     click.click();
     try {
   Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\f.gandhi.mohanam\\seleniumworkspace\\uploaderhandler.exe");
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='save']")).click();

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this blog post, it helped me.

[Uploading Files in Remote WebDriver](http://sauceio.com/index.php/2012/03/selenium-tips-uploading-files-in-remote-webdriver/)

It works using both local or remote webdriver.  Right now I have it working on Chrome, IE and Firefox.  I don't believe it works with the Safari driver.